# rbind three data bases using Rbind function

Tags: r, merge, concatenation, rbind, cbind

I know it's a newbie question, I have these 3 xlsx files with 3 three data bases of the same 14 variables,its a cross section data panel ,
All I want is to concatenate them in one single data base called eplt,
First, I import them

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(xlsx)
##Import the three data bases

epl_data<-read.xlsx("Notes_ETAB2016-2017.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1,header = TRUE)
epl_data2<-read.xlsx("Notes_ETAB2017-2018.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1,header = TRUE)
epl_data3<-read.xlsx("Notes_ETAB2018-2019.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1,header = TRUE)
## to render the number of rows in each of them
nrow(epl_data)
nrow(epl_data2)
nrow(epl_data3)
# I want to rbind the three sets together  

eplt<-rbind(epl_data,epl_data2,epl_data3)
```

the total number of rows is 29441, but when applying Rbind to bind them all together I get the error

```
> eplt<-rbind(epl_data,epl_data2,epl_data3)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

but the names of the variables in the 3 sets are the same
[image]
could someone please help, I only want to rebind 25000 observations, and leave the rest 4441 to compare it with the predictable obs of a multiple regression model,
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the names of the variables for all three dataframes please?

Comment: ok I will edit the post , thanks

Comment: Also, I encourage you to use `janitor::clean_names(data)` whenever you import data from Excel. It handles well the variable names problems when you import an excel file by making the variable names standarized

Comment: What `dplyr` and `ggplot2` functions are required?

Comment: `dplyr` solution isn't a great idea here for me. This function will keep all the columns for the three datasets, and will impute `NA` when a column isn't into certain dataframes (here, the `svt` column would have `NA`s for the first 2 datasets). When you have a few columns, you can find the one which is duplicated (Svt and SVT here), but it becomes really inneficient when you have a lots of variables.

Comment: @MonJeanJean I suspect you misunderstand the comment: in the question `dplyr` and `ggplot2`  are listed but there are no calls to any functions in either of these packages.

Comment: I am trying to rename svt with SVT with this : rename.variable(epl_data3, Svt=SVT)

Comment: Sorry @Peter, i saw another comment suggesting `dplyr::bind_rows()` function and I tagged you instead. My bad

Comment: @user2161721 `epl_data3 <- epl_data3 %>% rename(SVT = Svt)`

Comment: @MonJeanJean No no you are OK that was a previous comment I deleted as the OP posted the names and you spotted the name miss-match  so the comment was no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The third dataframes doesn't have the same names as the first two: Svt isn't to upper cases.

One way is to apply the names of one dataframe to the others:

```
colnames(epl_data2) <- colnames(epl_data)
colnames(epl_data3) <- colnames(epl_data)
```

But i recommand the package `janitor` whenever your data comes from Excel files. Indeed, it is common to have variable names issues. This package ensure a good formatting of your data column names:

```
epl_data <- janitor::clean_names(epl_data)
epl_data2 <- janitor::clean_names(epl_data2)
epl_data3 <- janitor::clean_names(epl_data3)
```

Therefore, the `rbind` should work

Comment: thanks it worked, but I need to make it 4000 obs less , meaning I want to concatenate the fist two with only 5588 rows from the third, to leave out 4000 obs, could you help me thanks

Comment: Saying you want to keep the 5588 first rows from the third: `rbind(epl_data, epl_data2, epl_data3 %>% slice_head(n = 5588))`, and if you want to select the 5588 by random, use `slice_sample(n=5588)` instead

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you have a mismatch in the variable name `'SVT'`. Here is an alternative that would make the column names lower case and bind them together in one dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

eplt <- list.files(pattern = 'Notes_ETAB2016-\\d+\\.xlsx') %>%
  map_df(~readxl::read_excel(.x) %>% rename_with(~tolower(.)))
```